# Sound object in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Simply I am trying to load a sound using an URL. But Its not loading.... So I am trying debug this. But I am getting a different thing. For that sound object I am getting

> bytesLoaded value is 15903

but the

> bytesToal value is 0

Is it possible to come like this???

Comment: Sounds like you need to post your code as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sound URL may be wrong. Where you are getting this URL? Is it from your local or from your db? Please check your URL... sound is not available, but you are trying to load means it will come like this. 
I don't know its correct or not... But try to confirm that URL....

Comment: I am getting URL from my db

Comment: Then please check your  db